# Error HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, error500

Buenos Días hoy me encontré con un problema al iniciar mi proyecto jsp, al ejecutarlo una de mis líneas me estaba dando error y no se porque estoy cansando de buscar las soluciones para esto les dejo mi código y capturas del problema. Tengo que entregar esto mañana :(

he buscado diferentes soluciones en foro para el problema y nada lei que también podía ser por falta de lib en web-inf/lib pero no es posible porque verifique y esta todo, y anteriormente me funcionaba necesito ayuda
corrección el problema <% es esto porque si quitos las líneas de <%h3 %>
sube el problema

```
<%@page import="Conexion.Conexion"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import ="java.sql.Statement" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="fondo">
            <img src="C:/Users/orlan/eclipse-workspace/Proyecto_Final/WebContent/Imagen/logo_utp_1_300.png" height ="100px" width="100px">
            <h1 class="conte">Vacuna UTP</h1>
    </header>
        <div>
        <nav class="navegacion">
                    <ul class = "menu">
                        <li><a href="Index.html"> Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href= "#">   Consulta y Eliminacion </a>
                            <ul class="submenu">    
                                <li><a href= "Consulta.jsp">Consulta De Los Registros</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Eliminar.jsp">Eliminar Registros</a><li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
    <section>
    
        <%
            String Cedula = request.getParameter("Cedula1");
            int Facultad = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Facultad2"));
            int TipoC = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("TipoCansulta"));
            String TipoU = request.getParameter("TipoUsuario");
            if(TipoC == 1){
                String Consulta = "Select Cantidad_Vac_SegundaD from Facultad where Id_Facultad='"+Facultad+"'";
                try{
                        Conexion cnn = new Conexion("C:/Users/orlan/eclipse-workspace/Proyecto_Final/WebContent/Proyecto_DS.accdb","","");
                        Connection con = cnn.Conexion_ini();
                        Statement pst1 = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery(Consulta);
                        while(rs.next()){
                            %><h3>La Cantidad De Estudiantes que posee La Segunda Dosis De La Facultad Elegida Es:</h3>
                            <h3><% out.print(rs.getInt(Facultad));%></h3><%
                    }
                        
                }catch(SQLException e){
                    out.print("Error"+e);
                }%>
    
        

        <form action="Consulta.jsp"> 
            <input type="submit" name="Regresar">
        </form>
    </section>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

El error me sale en la parte del <& del ultimo h3

[image: Error]

Comment: Hola, estaba chequeando el código. Veo que dice `request.getParameter("TipoCansulta")` , lo comento para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Comment: ¿No será que le falta cerrar el `if(TipoC == 1){` después del `catch`?  Veo cerrar el `catch` pero no el if con un `}`. Es decir, donde pone `}%>` quizás deberia poner `}}%>` (no tengo ni idea de jsp o tomcat, pero se contar pares :-))

Comment: @AleBuo Chicos Ya resolví el problema, nunca ponga un try para statement

Comment: @masterguru Chicos Ya resolví el problema, nunca ponga un try para statement

Comment: Gracias Por sus Comentarios :)